# Set background image in google app engine mail API

Tags: python, html, css, google-app-engine

Tried to insert background image in python. But I receive mail without Images (Text only). Why ?

```
class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
def post(self): 

message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="#### Team<abcd@gmail>",
                        subject="Your account has been approved")

    message.to = "David<qerer@gmail.com>"
    message.html = """  <html> 
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #backTabl { 
    width:100%x;
    height:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url(http://www.kerasote.com/files/background/tedkerasote_bkg_blue.jpg);
    }
    </style>
    </head>         
    <body>
    <table id="backTabl" border="0">       
      <tr>  <td width="3%"></td>
         <td valign="top"><br><font face="tahoma" size="2px" >Hi Nijin,   <br><br>             
          Your ###### account has been approved. You can now visit ##### <br><br>             

          Thanks for Using #### <br>
           </font></td> <td width="2%"></td> 
      </tr>
    </table>       
    </body>
    </html>
    """   
    message.send()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here appengine mail api has nothing to do with this.It just takes the html thats all. I even tried adding your code to mine and tested it with an dummy email. I was able to see the image. I think the problem is with your mail client.

Try this

```
mail.send_mail(sender="",
                 to="",
                 subject="",
                 body="",
                 html="your html")
```

Comment: Hi Abdul,
I Send the Email to my gmail account. When i take the original Messege in Gmail getting that : **Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed; delsp=yes**

Comment: @Nijin Narayanan, i opened the mail in thunderbird client.

Comment: mail.send_mail(sender="",
    
                 to=email_valid.email,
                 subject="Please validate your email",
                 body=body_text,
                 html=htmlbody_text)

Comment: @Nijin Narayanan, can you check the above method

Comment: @abdul Kader , I tried the above method but getting same in Web browser and thunderbird also
Here is my code http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7384181/mail_test.py
ScreenShot : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7384181/mail_image.png

Could you please check the code and lemme know if i did any wrong

Comment: @Nijin Narayanan, I think you should remove the css and add everything directly in html along in style . In that way it should work.

Comment: @Abdul Kader I did the coding that way also but No chance.. :(  I think , we need to specify the MIME type as text/html in attachement section. Any idea about that.

Comment: @Nijin Narayanan, I think the problem is with the way gmail parses email, the mail which had background in my exchange account, didn't had background in gmail when i forwarded that...

Answer (score 2):

Email clients are VERY picky about how they display HTML emails, they will often strip out css, rework markup and sanitise forms/javascript. This is likely not at issue with AppEngine but an issue with how email clients are presenting your emails. Checkout [this article](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2038/optimizing-css-presentation-in-html-emails/)

There are premium services (like [Litmus](http://litmus.com/) that can help you check your mail in many clients).